# Plotting Logistic Regression in R, but I keep getting errors

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I'm trying to plot a logistic regression in R, for a continuous independent variable and a dichotomous dependent variable. I have very limited experience with R, but my professor has asked me to add this graph to a paper I'm writing, and he said R would probably be the best way to create it. Anyway, I'm sure there are tons of mistakes here, but this is the sort of this previously suggested on StackOverflow:

```
ggplot(vvv, aes(x = vvv$V1, y=vvv$V2)) + geom_point() + stat_smooth(method="glm", family="binomial", se=FALSE) 
curve(predict(ggg, data.frame(V1=x), type="response"), add=TRUE)
```

where vvv is the name of my csv file (31 obs. of 2 variables), V1 is the continuous variable, and V2 is the dichotomous one. Also, ggg (List of 30?) is the following:

```
ggg<- glm(formula = vvv$V2 ~ vvv$V1, family = "binomial", data = vvv)
```

The ggplot function produces a graph of my data points, but no logistic regression curve. The curve function results in the following error:

```
 "Error in curve(predict(ggg, data.frame(V1 = x), type = "resp"), add = TRUE) : 'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'    

In addition: Warning message:'newdata' had 101 rows but variables found have 31 rows"
```

I'm not sure what the problem is, and I'm having trouble finding resources for this specific issue. Can anybody help? It would be greatly appreciated :)

Edit: Thanks to anyone who responded! My data, vvv, is the following, where the percent was the initial probability for presence/absence of a species in a specific area, and the 1 and 0 indicate whether or not a species ended up being observed.:

```
    V1  V2
1   95.00%  1
2   95.00%  0
3   95.00%  1
4   92.00%  1
5   92.00%  1
6   92.00%  1
7   92.00%  1
8   92.00%  1
9   92.00%  1
10  92.00%  1
11  85.00%  1
12  85.00%  1
13  85.00%  1
14  85.00%  1
15  85.00%  1
16  80.00%  1
17  80.00%  0
18  77.00%  1
19  77.00%  1
20  75.00%  0
21  70.00%  1
22  70.00%  0
23  70.00%  0
24  70.00%  1
25  70.00%  0
26  69.00%  1
27  65.00%  0
28  60.00%  1
29  50.00%  1
30  35.00%  0
31  25.00%  0
```

Comment: Could you try it on a smaller sample, just to fix your code? If not, posting your data might help.

Comment: we kinda need `vvvv` or simulated data to help

Comment: Without sample data to reproduce the error, it's difficult to help. I'm guessing that changing `ggg<- glm(formula = V2 ~ V1, family = "binomial", data = vvv)` will help with the predict(), but its just a guess.

Comment: It would be better if you put a `dput()` of the data rather than the output from the console. What is the class if V1? If they have a "%" i'm going to guess they are a factor which is probably not what you want. And what are the `x` values that you are using for the predict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MrFlick commented, V1 is probably a factor. So, first you have to change it to numeric class. This just substitutes "%" for nothing and divides by 100, so you will have proportions as numeric class:

```
vvv$V1<-as.numeric(sub("%","",vvv$V1))/100
```

Doing this, you can use your own code and you will have a plot for a logistic regression:

```
ggplot(vvv, aes(x = vvv$V1, y=vvv$V2)) + geom_point() + stat_smooth(method="glm", family="binomial", se=F)
```

This should print not only the points, but also the logistic regression curve. I don't understand what is the point of using `curves`. From what I could understand from your question, this is enough for what you need.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I changed V1 to a numeric class, but now I'm getting an error that says, `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1` I thought I had to add a curve function to have a regression line show up, but I'm a goober when it comes to R. Thanks again for the help

Comment: @hcbeswick, what is the class of vvv$V2? Use `class(vvv$V2)` to find out. It is probably a factor. Just use `vvv$V2<-as.numeric(as.character(vvv$V2))` to coerce it to a numeric class. With this you should be all set.